# 'Reversed' comparison operator in Python

Tags: python, comparison

```
class Inner():

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Inner):
            return self.x == other.x
        else:
            raise TypeError("Incorrect type to compare")

class Outer():

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = Inner(y)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Outer):
            return self.y == other.y
        elif isinstance(other, Inner):
            return self.y == other
        else:
            raise TypeError("Incorrect type to compare")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = Outer(1)
    b = Inner(1)

    print(a == b) # ok no problem
    print(b == a) # This will raise a type error
```

In the example I have inner and outer class. I have no control over what Inner implements just wanted to simulate the situation. I have only control over Outer's behavior. I want Outer instances to be able to compare to Inner instances (not just equality). With the given implementation only the first comparison works because that is calling Outer's `__eq__` method allowed to be compared to Outer and Inner instances but the second one is calling Inner's `__eq__` which will not allow the comparison to Outer - heck it doesn't know Outer exists why should it bother to implement it.
Is there a way to get the second type of comparison to work, with something similar like the `__radd__` and such functions.
I know for instance in C++ you resolve this with inline operator definitions, but we don't have such in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to put too fine a point on it: `Inner.__eq__` is broken. At the very least, rather than throwing an error it should [`return NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented), which would allow Python to try the reverse comparison:

> When `NotImplemented` is returned, the interpreter will then try the
>   reflected operation on the other type, or some other fallback,
>   depending on the operator. If all attempted operations return
>   `NotImplemented`, the interpreter will raise an appropriate exception.

Better yet it would use [*"duck typing"*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-duck-typing), rather than insisting on a specific class (unless the class, rather than its interface, is an explicitly important part of the comparison):

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    try:
        return self.x == other.x
    except AttributeError:
        return NotImplemented
```

---

However, as you say you cannot control this, you will have to manually implement similar functionality, for example:

```
def compare(a, b):
    """'Safe' comparison between two objects."""
    try:
        return a == b
    except TypeError:
        return b == a
```

as there is no such thing as `__req__` in [Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).