# Python 3: Comparing built-in objects to custom objects

Tags: python, duplicates, comparison, equality

When comparing ints and floats, Python 3 seems to take a bit of liberty:

```
>>> 1 == 1.0
True
>>> 1.0 == 1
True
```

I work on implementation of dozenal (base-12) numbers, and have overridden the `__eq__` method to emulate the same behavior, and it almost works:

```
>>> a = Dozenal(1)
>>> a
DozenalInt('1')
>>> a == 1
debug_print: DozenalInt('1').__eq__(1) called
True
>>> 1 == a
debug_print: DozenalInt('1').__eq__(1) called
True
>>> a == 1.0
debug_print: DozenalInt('1').__eq__(1.0) called
True
>>> 1.0 == a
False
```

Why does it not try to call the reverse equality test in the last case, as it clearly does in others?

PS

`__eq__` code really isn’t much to look at:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    print('debug_print: {}.__eq__({}) called'.format(self.__repr__(), other.__repr__()))
    other = Dozenal._verify_other(other)
    if self.is_integer() and other.is_integer():
        return int(self) == int(other)
    return self._doz_cipher == other._doz_cipher

def _verify_other(other):
    if isinstance(other, Dozenal):
        return other
    elif isinstance(other, (int, float, str)):
        return Dozenal(other)
    else:
        return NotImplemented
```

Comment: The solution was already posted on this question: "[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434094/reversed-comparison-operator-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434094/reversed-comparison-operator-in-python)"

Comment: Am I to understand that float’s `__eq__` is broken (does not return `NotImplemented`), but int’s `__eq__` works fine? Is that an oversight, or an expected behavior?

Comment: And, as a consequence, am I to understand that there is no way to make this work with the default `==` operator?

Comment: @CBlew, no, the _OP's_ code was broken in that post as the `__eq__` of _their class_ is responsible for doing any comparisons involving it.

Comment: @ForceBru, and no direct solution was offered in that thread, only a workaround that would use a custom function instead of `==`. Right?

Comment: @CBlew, wait, you wanna say your custom `__eq__` isn't called when you do `1.0 == a`? I've just constructed a class with a similar operator and it worked flawlessly. BTW, I think this dupe target is wrong as it's not about built-in types.

Comment: @ForceBru, exactly. On `1 == a` custom `__eq__` **is** called, but on `1.0 == a` it isn’t. I feel like it isn’t Python’s fault, but still can’t figure out where I went wrong.